# How to write array of data types in c

Tags: arrays, c, types

I want to sizeof of data types in for-cycle. I wrote function with macros that print sizeof of argument (argument is data type). I need to use struct with data-types-elements and indexing them. How can I realize it or how to work around this problem?

Code:

```
#define t_array = [ int, float ];
#define t_size(type) printf("%d", sizeof(type));

int main()
{
    t_size(t_array[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot do this in C. Members of a struct do not have any index. They are only accesed using their names. Therefore you cannot iterate over the members in a loop. You can also not have an array of different types. On a sidenote: `%d` is wrong format for printing a value of type `size_t`. Use `%zu` instead.

Comment: Thanks fo your answer, what the struct of data I can use to solve my problem? Or is it impossible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to have an array of data types.

Instead you can use preprocessor to have an array of tokens.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRAY  int, float

#define GET_1(_1) _1
#define GET_2(_1,...) GET_1(__VA_ARGS__)
#define GET_3(_1,...) GET_2(__VA_ARGS__)
#define GET_N2(_3,_2,_1,N,...)  GET##N
#define GET_N(...)  GET_N2(__VA_ARGS__,_3,_2,_1)
// GET idx argument from comma separated tokens
#define GET(array, idx)  GET_N(array)(array)

int main() {
   printf("%zu\n", sizeof(GET(ARRAY, 0)));
}
```

Or you can store the sizes (and other type-abstract) properties in array with elements for each type. (This is most importantly used with virtual functions that abstract operations on each type and results in nice non-spaghetti code, but calling a virtual function results in runtime overhead).

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct type_property {
    size_t size;
};

#define TYPE_PROPERTY_INIT(type)  { sizeof(type) }

struct type_property properties[] = {
    TYPE_PROPERTY_INIT(int),
    TYPE_PROPERTY_INIT(float),
};

int main() {
   printf("%zu\n", properties[0].size);
}
```

Etc, there are other ways for writing type-abstract or templated code in C programming language that use these in a clever way. Like you can generate functions with preprocessor:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TYPESTUFF_DECL(SUFFIX, TYPE) \
size_t typestuff_size_##SUFFIX(void) { \
    return sizeof(TYPE); \
}

TYPESTUFF_DECL(0, int)
TYPESTUFF_DECL(1, float)

int main() {
   printf("%zu\n", typestuff_size_0());
}
```

Or you can have a whole file that is templated over tokens to generate those functions (see ex. [STC](https://github.com/tylov/STC) for usage):

```
// typestuff.h

#ifndef TYPESTUFF_H_
#define TYPESTUFF_H_
#define TYPESTUFF_CONCAT(a, b)  a##b
#define TYPESTUFF_CONCATX(a, b)  TYPESTUFF_CONCAT(a, b)
#endif

static size_t TYPESTUFF_CONCATX(typestuff_size_, SUFFIX)(void) {
    return sizeof(TYPE);
}

#undef SUFFIX
#undef TYPE

// main.c
#include <stdio.h>

#define SUFFIX 0
#define TYPE int
#include <typestuff.h>

#define SUFFIX 1
#define TYPE float
#include <typestuff.h>

int main() {
   printf("%zu\n", typestuff_size_0());
}
```

Or you can enumerate each type and write big ugly very bad to maintain case statements, please don't do it, because you'll end up with [this DLMS library](https://github.com/Gurux/GuruxDLMS.c/blob/df62dd6c652537a16a04189e957239e851577bcb/development/src/cosem.c#L58):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

enum types {
   TYPE_INT,
   TYPE_FLOAT,
};

size_t types_sizeof(enum types idx) {
   switch (idx) {
      case TYPE_INT: return sizeof(int);
      case TYPE_FLOAT: return sizeof(float);
   };
   assert(0);
}

int main() {
   printf("%zu\n", sizeof(types_sizeof(0)));
}
```

Note that to print `size_t` as result from `sizeof` you should use `%zu`.